# How to map bytes from 128 to 255 to the equivalent UTF16-LE surrogate pairs

Tags: java, unicode, utf-16, surrogate-pairs

I'm trying to achieve this:

I have a PDF byte[] in java web service that I must send as a base64 string to a .NET client that does this to reconstruct the file.

```
Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.Default, Convert.FromBase64String(inputJava))
```

I cannot change the client code and right now the java web service is calling another .NET web service that does this to turn the byte[] into a base64 string:

```
System.Text.Encoding.Convert(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252), System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, b);
```

Beside the base64 that I can make in various ways (e.g. with org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64), I have to turn the original byte[] into a UTF-16LE byte[]...

I tried this:

```
byte[] output = new byte[b.length * 2];
for(int i=0; i < b.length; i++) 
{
  int val = b[i];
  if(val < 0) val += 256;

  output[2*i + 0] = (byte) (val);   
  output[2*i + 1] = 0; 
}
```

This works fine for values below 128 (e.g. for 1 => 0100, 2 => 0200, ... , 127 => 7F00) but for values above (128 -> 255) I don't know how to get the equivalent 2bytes values; I know that for byte 156 (9C) the corresponding value is 8301 (0x5301) and for byte 224 (E0) the corresponding value is 12501 (0x7D01) but I didn't manage to find an algorithm to get all the other values.

Is there a mapping table between byte value and the corresponding UTF-16LE surrogate pair or an algorithm to map values from 128 to 255?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you want, but surely [UTF-8](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629) and [UTF-16](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2781) contain everything you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. It looks like that only bytes from 128 to 159 need the surrogate pairs. I use this piece of code to emulate .NET Unicode encoding:

```
public class Encoder {
   static Map<Integer, Integer> mapTiny = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {
        public Integer get(Object key) {
            Integer code = super.get(key);
            if (code == null)
                code = (Integer) key;
            return code;
        }
    };

    static {
        mapTiny.put(128,8364);
        mapTiny.put(130,8218);
        mapTiny.put(131,402);
        mapTiny.put(132,8222);
        mapTiny.put(133,8230);
        mapTiny.put(134,8224);
        mapTiny.put(135,8225);
        mapTiny.put(136,710);
        mapTiny.put(137,8240);
        mapTiny.put(138,352);
        mapTiny.put(139,8249);
        mapTiny.put(140,338);
        mapTiny.put(142,381);
        mapTiny.put(145,8216);
        mapTiny.put(146,8217);
        mapTiny.put(147,8220);
        mapTiny.put(148,8221);
        mapTiny.put(149,8226);
        mapTiny.put(150,8211);
        mapTiny.put(151,8212);
        mapTiny.put(152,732);
        mapTiny.put(153,8482);
        mapTiny.put(154,353);
        mapTiny.put(155,8250);
        mapTiny.put(156,339);
        mapTiny.put(158,382);
        mapTiny.put(159,376);
    }


public static String encode(byte[] b) throws IOException {

        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
        ByteArrayOutputStream convFileByteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int i = in.read();
        while (i != -1) {
            convFileByteArray.write(new byte[] { (byte) (mapTiny.get(i) & 0xff), (byte) ((mapTiny.get(i) >> 8) & 0xff) });
            i = in.read();
        }
        return Base64.encodeToString(convFileByteArray.toByteArray(), false);
    }

}
```

Comment: fyi, this is basically the windows-1252 encoding http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252, and i believe that my example above should have accomplished the same thing.

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I tried, but surprisely it did not work. Maybe it's a bug in my VM...

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need surrogate pairs; they are a construct for dealing with characters outside Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), and all windows-1252 characters are in BMP.

The official windows-1252 (alias cp1252) to Unicode mapping table is
http://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1252.TXT
It’s a plain text file in easy-to-process format, so if you don’t find an existing tool for the conversion, it should be rather straightforward to write mapping based on that file.

The file is indirectly cited in the official IANA registry:
http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets

Comment: Thanks, using the list in the link you provided I managed to understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
byte[] encoded = new String(b, "windows-1252").getBytes("UTF-16LE");
```

Comment: +1: I would have used `ISO-8859-1` instead of `windows-1252` or even just `new String(b, 0);` just to be sure there is no translation.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - why ISO-8859-1?  the OP shows that the data was encoded using the windows 1252 charset.  although, i guess if the data is really base64 encoded, it shouldn't really matter either way.  could use US-ASCII just as well.

Comment: @jtahlborn: I tried with that, and also with different charset combination but unfortunately I did't manage to make it working as espected: The base64 string encoded in java differs from the one generated in .NET and inspecting the byte[] before the encoding I see that the surrogate pairs resulting for bytes above 128 are different. I suspect that Microsoft's Encoding.Unicode is some how different from java's UTF-16LE. Also as someone previously advised me it should not matter the first charset (Cp1252) because the file is a binary file, not an encoded text file...

Comment: @Nicola - how do the chars differ?  and which byte[], specifically, are you inspecting?  maybe if you showed some more code...

Comment: @jtahlborn: as an example: byte 0x90 in the original byte[] becomes with .NET: 0x9000 whereas in java becomes 0xFDFF (using windows-1252 as encoding). If instead I use iso-8859-1 that specific char is right but other are not encoded well. Thanks, Nicola

Comment: @Nicola - how do you have the character "0x90" in base64 encoded data?

Comment: @jtahlborn: I get 0x90 in the original byte[] not in the base64 string. To check the different behavior I did this: first I got the Unicode byte[] in .NET and the UTF-16LE byte[] in java, then I compared the two byte[]; when in the original PDF byte[] I found the value 0x90 the corrisponding values in the encoded byte[]s are different, 0x9000 in .NET and 0xFDFF in Java. Obiviously if I do base64 on both environments the two strings are different and the client machines are able to reconstruct only the .NET generated version

Comment: @Nicola - when you used ISO-8859-1 instead of cp1252, what characters differed?

Comment: I finally get it working! I found that only some bytes above 127 need the surrogate pairs. In case it would help other people with my same problem, here is the mapping table between the original byte and the corresponding UTF-16LE equivalent to the .NET encoding Encoding.Unicode, please see the answer below. Thanks! - @jtahlborn